# Variable referenced before it's assigned

Tags: python

**UPDATE:** The if statement is not being executed, which is strange since I tested the script outside of Django and worked just in Python only.

I know this question has been asked many times on here, but I can't find an answer that helps me figure out my error. Here is the error I get:

```
local variable 'what_i_need' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my code in VIEWS:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def test(request):
    someURL = "https://www.example.com/"
    urlOpen = urlopen(someURL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlOpen)
    for x in soup.findAll('span'):
        if 'something' in str(x):
            info = x.get_text()
            info = info.split()
            info = info[0]
            info = info.replace(".", '')
            what_i_need = info
    return HttpResponse(what_i_need)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `if` statement. If it is never executed, `what_i_need` is never initialised and hence the error (since you cannot pass an unitialized variable to `HttpResponse`). Just initialize it to `None` or the like (according to your needs)

```
def test(request):
    someURL = "https://www.example.com/"
    urlOpen = urlopen(someURL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlOpen)
    what_i_need = None            # Initialized here
    for x in soup.findAll('span'):
        if 'something' in str(x):
            info = x.get_text()
            info = info.split()
            info = info[0]
            info = info.replace(".", '')
            what_i_need = info
    return HttpResponse(what_i_need)
```

Comment: You're right. The if statement is not executing -- which is strange -- because when I test the script not in Django, it works. Any ideas?

Comment: That depends on what `soup.findAll('span')` returns.

Comment: Try printing the result of `soup.findAll('span')` as a seperate Django Page? And figure it out.